# MS Bot Framework (Nodejs): How to change language of Prompt dialog?

Tags: node.js, botframework

The problem is when I use Prompts for example:

```
 Prompts.confirm(session, "Are you sure?");
```

Bot asks:

```
Are your sure? (1. Yes, 2. No)
```

It's ok, because it uses default language, but when I need to ask something on other language this additional part `(1. Yes, 2. No)` doesn't change. So how can I change language for Prompt or for all dialogs from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default prompt `confirm_yes` and `confirm_no` values within your own `BotBuilder.json` file.

Take a look at the localization example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-localization/app.js to see how where to place the BotBuilder.json file.

Here's an example of my bot's `locale/en/BotBuilder.json`:
`{
    "confirm_yes": "yep",
    "confirm_no": "nope"

}`

and `locale/es/BotBuilder.json`: 
`{
    "confirm_yes": "sip",
    "confirm_no": "nop"

}`

Comment: Yep, it works, thank you. Maybe you know when the new version of botbuilder npm package will be builded which includes this changes?

Comment: I believe the aim is to update in about a week's time, maybe a little sooner!